# import dlibでzsh: segmentation fault pythonがでます

Tags: python

python 2.7.10
pyenvを使用

```
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May  7 2016, 10:54:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
zsh: segmentation fault  python
```

になります。。。

dlibを使用しているpythonを実行すると

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import dlib
from skimage import io
```

の`import dlib`のところで

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gen_detector.py", line 7, in 
    import dlib
ImportError: No module named dlib
```

になります。。。

おそらくdlibにpathが通っていないからだと思ったのですがzshrcをみてみると

```
export PYENV_ROOT=$HOME/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

を書いていたのでpathは問題ないかと思いました。`import numpy`などはうまくいきます。

かなりハマっておりますので解決方法をご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします！

Comment: @kcrt さん
ご回答ありがとうございます！
まず1の `which python` の結果ですが、`/Users/YYYYYY/.pyenv/shims/python`になっていました。

次に2ですが`PHTHONPATH`の設定をzshrcから消しシェルを再起動、pip install をしましたがすでにinstallされていると出て`import dlib` も同じエラーが出ました。。

Comment: 他には、`dlib`のインストールに必要な`boost-python`の導入方法はどうでしょうか。もし、HomeBrewで`boost-python`をinstallするとbottle済みのものが使用されます。`pyenv`の環境と同一のものを使用するために、一度アンインストールした後に、`brew install --build-from-source boost-python`で再度導入して、その後、dlibを入れ直してみるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: （使ったことないのでリンクポンと貼るだけで申し訳ないですが）[これ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834397/installing-dlib-python-module-getting-segfault)ですかね

Comment: 度々のご回答ありがとうございます！アドバイスいただいた上記の方法も試してみましたがエラーメッセージも変わらずでした。。
もう少し考えてみます！

Answer (score 1):

**1. pyenv init**

`which python`の結果は`/Users/YYYYYY/.pyenv/shims/python`になっていますか？もし`/usr/bin/python`になっていたら、`pyenv`のpythonは使用されていません。
`if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi`
を`.bash_profile`などに追加しているかご確認下さい。
これを行うことで、`$PATH`に`~/.pyenv/shims`が含まれるようになり、これにより`python`・`pip`などが適切に使用できます。
これを行わずにインストールしたライブラリは、`.pyenv`下ではなくシステムにインストールされているかもしれません。

参考: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#advanced-configuration

**2. `PYTHONPATH`の設定**

`pyenv`を使用しているので、必要なライブラリは`~/.pyenv/versions/XXXXXX/lib/`にインストールされていると思います。
`PYTHONPATH`を設定してしまうと、pyenvでインストールしたライブラリではなく、システムに入っているライブラリを優先して読み込むことになってしまいます。

```
% python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Users/YYYYYY/.pyenv/versions/XXXXXX/lib/python35.zip', '/Users/YYYYYY/.pyenv/versions/XXXXXX/lib/python3.5', ...
```

といったように、sys.pathが適切になっていれば、`PYTHONPATH`の設定は不要です。

というわけで、`PYTHONPATH`の設定を消す→`pyenv init`を設定ファイルに追加→シェルを再起動して`pyenv versions`で(systemではなく)使用したいバージョンが適切に設定されているか確認→`pip install`でライブラリをインストール
といったところをいま一度御確認ください。